# How to constrain the GridLayout's width to be less than the parent's width?

Tags: android, layout, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout defined in the XML layout file as:

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
    </GridLayout>
```

Because the width is `match_parent`, I expected the GridLayout to arrange the buttons such that only as many buttons are shown per row as are necessary to keep the width of the row less than the parent's width.

However, this is not the result I am seeing. The three buttons are all showing up in the first row extending beyond the parent's width as shown in the image below. What is the way to achieve the output that I am looking for?

[image: The output I am getting - all buttons in one row and extending beyond the parent width]

Answer (score 0):

Is `GridLayout` a requirement? How about having `LinearLayout` instead and giving each view equal weights?

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Or replacing `GridLayout` with `TableLayout` and wrapping your buttons into `TableRow` like so:

```
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow>
                    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
                    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
                    <Button android:text="ababababababababababababababababababababab" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Comment: GridLayout promises to reflow the children views across the rows if there is no space left in a row. I have a list of dynamically generated views that I want to show in a grid. I don't think these two options will get this result.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `GridView` then?

Comment: `GridView` doesn't provide the flexibility of having different widths in a particular column

Comment: You could possibly wrap your button in layout and adjust button's width in that layout/column.

Comment: :) That will help when you want to make the button smaller than a column. What if you want the button to span over two or more columns?